# Expresso Store - Change order_id start point

Tags: expresso-store, mysql

My client would like the order numbers (order_id)'s to start at 30000 (thirty thousand) rather than starting at 0.

Looking at the database I can see in the exp_store_orders table that order_id is set to auto_increment. This would lead me to believe that I should be able to bump up the numbers by just doing the following on that table:

```
ALTER TABLE exp_store_orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 30000
```

As this site is almost ready to go live I don't want to FUBAR it, so I'd appreciate confirmation that this is the only place I need to make a change!

Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it. To clarify this for others, you will need to open up PHPMyAdmin, or any other SQL client which will let you run SQL queries directly.

You can also go to Tools > Data > SQL Manager > Database Query Form in the ExpressionEngine control panel.

Then run this query, replacing `30000` with the order ID you want to assign to the next order:

```
ALTER TABLE `exp_store_orders` AUTO_INCREMENT = 30000;
```

This won't break anything, because it's exactly how Store generates new order IDs (using the MySQL auto increment counter).

Comment: @Adrian After deleting the orders in the store admin panel, there are still all the incomplete/unprocessed orders in the exp_store_orders table. How can I get back to a clean slate? Are there concerns with the other exp_store_order_ tables?

Comment: @Jbird at the top of your admin panel page for orders there is a drop down that allows you to sort by order status if you choose incomplete you can then delete the rest of the orders.